# Random Walk and Moving Average for Stock Market Model

Tags: simulation, model, random-generation

I model a stock price with a completely random walk:

- In each step I multiply the price with normal distributed random number with an mean of 1.
- Then I compute a signal, which is True if the moving average of the last 10 prices is above the current price.
- When I now look on the mean of the prices where the signal is True and find that the average of these is above the mean of the prices that have a False signal.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal

def moving_average(x, w):
    return scipy.signal.convolve2d(x, np.ones(( 1, w)), 'same') / w

change = np.random.normal(loc=1.0, scale=0.01, size=(10_000, 10_000)) # Create 10.000 time series with 10.000 elemts
price = change.cumprod(axis=1)

price = price[:, 1000:] # Skip the first 1000 prices

avgPrice  = moving_average(price, 10)
buy = avgPrice > price
sale = price > avgPrice

print(np.mean(price[buy]), np.mean(price[sale]))
```

```
(0.9809647426274503, 1.0068282858753526)
```

I would have expected that both means are identical, because the changes are independent of each other. But they are not. Why?

I also tried a different random walk with

```
change = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.01, size=(10_000, 10_000)
price = np.cumsum(change, axis=1)
```

with a similar result

```
(-0.0015839832665335697, 0.025289114378696673)
```

Comment: Welcome to CV, Rüdiger! At first glance, without looking deeper, the results look ok to me - they are estimates (obtained by simulation) of identical quantities. Try to run the program again - do you get exactly the same results?

Comment: Yes, many times. But even a single invocation does 10.000 time series with 10.000 elements.

Comment: I do not use python, and have no idea if the random number generator starts in the same position every time. Otherwise it seems strange that you get exactly the same results every time. You could try to see what happens if you set the random seed manually to different values.

Comment: what is `priceb` (first code, last line) - just a copy-paste error?

Comment: Oh, I think I can see what happens (perhaps). Has nothing to do with python. Why do you expect that both average prices (buy and sell) should be equal?

Comment: I didn't get exactly the same results. But they were similar: the buy prices below the sell prices .

Comment: Good! reading your program in the question (without understanding all details), I thought it is by design and should give you such results :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the moving average function (that I copied without much thinking from stackverflow). It takes values in the future into the average.

The correct moving average would be:

```
def moving_average(x, w):
    kernel = np.zeros((1, 2*w+1), dtype=int)
    kernel[0, :w+1] = 1
    count = np.sum(kernel)
    
    return scipy.signal.convolve2d(x, kernel, 'same') / count
```

This leads to nearly identical prices (with different compare results) for the cumsum model and a very slight biased values for the cumprod (which could be caused by the multiplication).